# How do I reference addresses of eks node group members in terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have an an EKS cluster created with Terraform using aws_eks_cluster and a managed node group using aws_eks_node_group.

I also have certain resources outside AWS, behind a firewall.

I'd like to have Terraform create rules in the firewall to grant the node group members access to those resources.

I don't see a way to get their IP addresses. I expected to be able to say something like `aws_eks_node_group.foo.instances.ip` but looking at what `terraform console` tells me about my node group, I see nothing of that nature.

I'm new to Terraform and EKS so I might be completely off track. Is there a way to get those addresses?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use IPs. You want to give those nodes a named security group. Then in that security group you want the nodes to access you allow that named security group through and no ips.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Mike. The firewall in question is outside the AWS ecosystem, so security groups don't help. My question didn't make that clear. Sorry about that.